# Node JS Image Binary String

Tags: node.js, etsy

I'm working with Etsy api uploading images like this [example](https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/tutorials/listings#adding-an-image-to-a-listing), and it requires the images be in binary format. Here is how I'm getting the image binary data:

```
async function getImageBinary(url) {
    const imageUrlData = await fetch(url);
    const buffer = await imageUrlData.buffer();
    return buffer.toString("binary");
}
```

However Etsy says it is not a valid image file. How can I get the image in the correct format, or make it in a valid binary format?

Answer (score 0):

Read this for a working example of Etsy API
https://github.com/etsy/open-api/issues/233#issuecomment-927191647

Etsy API is buggy and has an inconsistent guide. You might think of using 'binary' encoding for the buffer because the docs saying that the data type is string but you actually don't need to. Just put the default encoding.

Also currently there is a bug for image upload, try to remove the Content-type header. Better read the link above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).